# React Tree view component

Tags: reactjs, treeview

I need to implement a tree view component with React.
When the component renders firstly on the page, I need to fetch and render the parent nodes and child nodes of the first nesting level. After that, if user clicks on a child node, I should fetch its child nodes and so on. What is the best way to implement this? Could you recommend some article to read or a good library?

Answer (score 0):

I regularly use rc-tree in many of my applications.
[npm-rc-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-tree)

It handles your use case of lazy loading the levels of the tree.